# Javascript calculations returning wrong numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm trying to make two input fields calculate their value off one another. Here is my code so far:

```
function strToNumber (str) { 
    return Number(str.replace(/\D/g,''));
}

var number_2_calc;
var number_1 = strToNumber($("#number_1").val());
var number_2 = strToNumber($("#number_2").val());

$("#number_2").focusout(function(){
    if(number_2 == 0) {
        $("#number_2").val("");
    } else {
        number_2_calc = number_2 +(number_1 * 0.1);
        $("#number_2").val(number_2_calc);
    }
});

$("#number_1").focusout(function() {
    if(number_2 == 0) {
        $("#number_2").val("");
    } else {
        //not sure if necessary to create seperate vars here
        var number_2_stored = strToNumber($("#number_1").val());
        var number_1_stored =strToNumber($("#number_2").val());

        number_2_calc = 0;

        number_2_calc = number_2_stored +(number_1_stored * 0.1);
        Math.round(number_2_calc).toFixed(2);
        $("#number_2").val(number_2_calc);
    }
});
```

So I'm trying to make it when you fill out either field then focus out it will change the input accordingly. This works fine when number_2 focuses out, but when you go back and change number_1 the values get messy. Probably just overlooking something simple, because this shouldn't be that difficult.

Comment: `values get messy.` this is not descriptive enough. Please give expected output, and what you got.

Comment: Your code will strip out periods, for like `1.1`

Comment: There are a number of issues with this code - http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript hope in here and we can probably point more out

Comment: Alright, I'll add some of the values I'm getting to the post.

Answer (score 1):

When you round the result, you need to assign back to "number_2_calc".

```
number_2_calc = Math.round(number_2_calc).toFixed(2);
```

Comment: Note that will incorrectly round the number. He wants `number_2_calc =  (Math.round((number_2_calc)*100)/100).toFixed(2)`

Comment: @RUJordan I suppose he might; it's not clear to me what the point of the code is supposed to be.

Comment: sorry, didn't mention he's in the JS room and we're talking about it. (I'm not gonna answer, so you can edit this into yours if you like, or not, it's whatev)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I found out my biggest problem was assuming Math.round(number_2_calc).toFixed(2); altered the value of the var. Thanks for all the help everyone!